# How to pass an object from an azure data factory lookup to a databricks notebook?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

Using a lookup activity in ADF to get list of tables that I want to output to Databricks notebook which will be used to run the code.

- For Loop Object dynamic content `@activity('Lookup IngestionControl').output.value`
- The error I'm getting is
  `The value type in key 'TABLENAME' is not expected type 'System.String'`

Attempted Solution: `@String(activity('Lookup IngestionControl').output.value)`

- `Warning: Expression of type: 'String' does not match the field: 'items'`
- Ran it with the warning and get an error because the object is type array and cannot be converted to a string

Answer (score 0):

You can only pass a string into the databricks API. ADF uses the databricks jobs API when it calls a notebook / jar.

https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html

What i usually do is convert the array into a json string. Can do this in SQL or in ADF doesnt really matter. Depending on which one you are trying to do would change how i would do it.

`@activity('Lookup IngestionControl').output.value` tells me its a Lookup activity. I would just create the json from sql and pass it through ADF and into your notebook.